# If I put the volume under +- 40%, the sound stops

Tags: 14.04, sound

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus laptop.

The sound is working. But whenever I try to adjust the volume, if I ever dare to put it under +- 40%, the sound violently shuts down. It's working again if I put back the volume above +- 40%. To be very precise, 100% of volume is really equivalent to the full "loudness" my headset/skeakers are able to output and 40% is really is equivalent to +- 40% of the full loudness (which is still pretty loud sometimes). So if I want some quiet music it's just impossible to get it using the volume control of Ubuntu and I have to reduce the volume in my player.

That behavior is always the same whether I'm using the speakers of my laptop, a headset using the mini-jack connector or an USB headset.

Anyone has an idea how to solve that problem?

Thanks in advance.

For the PulseAudio log: https://gist.github.com/nicolas-van/bced4c5659cfe97ca7a7

Comment: Do you mean the application stops playing sound or does the application still play but you can't hear anything? Does it look like PulseAudio is crashing and being restarted? (The indicator in Unity changes when that happens.) A [verbose PulseAudio Log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log) might be helpful to see what happens in PA when when you do that. Also please [edit] your question and – even though you said that it also happens on USB – add the model number of your laptop.

Comment: The music still plays in the application and PulseAudio doesn't crash. I wasn't clear about this: **if, after putting the volume under 40%, I put it back over 40% I can hear the sound again**. This is not a problem related were the sound stops completely and I have restart PulseAudio or Ubuntu to get it back. This problem is only related to the volume where, basically, I can't get a lower volume because volume < 40% = no volume at all. Also, for the laptop it's an Asus 730u. For the log I will post it.

Comment: I added the Pulse Audio log.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I have looked at your log and found error, however I don't know how to correctly interpret these or help you further, and it doesn't look like someone else around here does. Please open a bug for PulseAudio on Launchpad and contact the members on the PulseAudio mailing list.